# Create Database Source - Define Joins - Join by multiple colums

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to create a DataSource in Pentaho, but I cant define a join by two or more columns.

For example: my invoice table has the PK defined as [ClientId,InvoiceId] so diferent Clients can have the same InvoiceId. So the join with the table InvoiceProduct should be based by those two columns.

Yet Pentaho only allows me to select only one column from each table to define the join.

This is the official documentation from Pentaho: [Create Database Sources](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0L0/0A0/060). On #9 it talks about Join Definition, but never mentions PKs that have more than one column (which IMHO is quite common), so probably I'm doing something wrong.

Can anyone please point me out on how to define a join that involves more than one column?

Hope I made myself clear.

Best regards,
    Federico.

- Pentaho 8
- Mysql 5.6
- Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried with two keys, but it is not working you can generate a checksum value using checksum step and then use it while joining.